# What is atomic in boost / C++0x / C++1x / computer sciences?

Tags: c++11, atomic

What is atomic in C/C++ programming ?

I just visited the dearly cppreference.com (well I don't take the title for granted but wait for my story to finish), and the home changed to describe some of the C++0x/C++1x (let's call it C+++, okay ?) new features.

There was a mysterious and never seen by my zombie programmer's eye, the new `<atomic>`.

I guess its purpose is not to program atomic bombs or black holes (but I highly doubt this could have ANY connection with black holes, I don't know how those 2 words slipped here), but I'd like to know something:

What is the purpose of this feature ? Is it a type ? A function ? Is it a data container ? Is it related to threads ? May it have some relation with python's "import antigravity" ? I mean, we are programming here, we're not bloody physicist or semanticists !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is intended for multithreading. It avoids you to have concurrent threads mix operations. An atomic operation is an indivisible operation. You can’t observe such an operation half-done from any thread in the system; it’s either done or not done. With an atomic operation you cannot get a data race between threads. In a real world analogy you will use atomic not for physics but for semaphores and other traffic signals on roads. Cars will be threads, roads will be rules, locations will be data. Semaphores will be atomic. You don't need semaphores when there is only one car on all roads, right?

Answer (score 2):

Atomic refers to something which is not divisible.

An atomic expression is one that is actually executed by a single operation.

---

For example `a++` is not atomic, since to exec it you need first to get the value of `a`, then to sum 1 to it, then to store the result into `a`.

Reading the value of an `int` should instead be atomic.

---

Atomic-ness is important in shared-memory parallel computations (eg: when using threads): because it tells you that an expression will give you the result you're expecting no matter what the other threads are doing.

Comment: actually according to Herb Sutter ++ is atomic for `std::atomic<int>`

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK you could use atomic functions to create your own semaphores etc. The name atomic came from atom, you cant break it smaller, so those function calls can't be "broken apart" and paused by the operating system. This is for thread programming.